# I have an ASP.NET MVC Razor WebGrid to where I would like to copy current row only (3, 6, 7, 8, 9) column values to a row that has dropdown id values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

Functionality: when I select the drop-down list box, the current values are shown in a message box, asking you if you want to copy the row info of 5 cells in the columns to the empty row in green. If you choose "Yes", then it will copy them to that row then clear what it copied in the current row there after. If you choose "No", then it will cancel, the box will become unchecked and drop-down box will hide once again.

I cannot figure out how to copy the info to the green row designated by the id from the drop-down box?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

WebGrid:

```
[Code]

@model YardDog.Model.YardDogModel
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Yard Dog";
    WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.LocationData, canPage: true, canSort: true, 
                                  sortDirectionFieldName: "Section", rowsPerPage: 50);
    webGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>Index</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YardDogStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
/>

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
                    <div class="DivDropDown">
            @{ int firstRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 1;
                int lastRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 
 webGrid.Rows.Count();
            }
            <div id="RowCountTop"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of 
  @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>

            <br />
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = 
 "formYardDog" }))
            {
                //Loop to Get Dictionary List Buttons with Distinct Section Values.
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Section.Count; i++)
                {

                    <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" 
  value=@Model.Section[i].Value id="ddlSectionButtons" , new { 
onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" 
} />

                }
                <!-- All Sections Button for PlantLocation -->
                <button text="All" value=" " type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => 
model.Section)" , new { onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" onClick="focusMe(this);" 
id="ddlSectionAllButton" class="ddlSectionButtons" placeholder="All" hidden="hidden" 
})>All</button>
                <!-- No need for Second Section Drop-Down Box -->
                //Html.LabelFor(model => model.Section, "All", new { onchange = 
    "document.forms[0].submit();", id = "ddlSectionAllButtonLbl", Class 
    ="ddlSectionButtons", placeholder = "All" })

            }

            <img id="OpenPanelButton" class="OpenPanelButton" 
  src="~/images/OpenPanelButton.PNG" href="" />

            <!-- Begin Collaspable Panel with Div -->
            <div id="panel">
                <br />
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Section, Model.Section, "Section", 
     new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlSection", @class = 
  "ddlSection" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlantLocation, Model.PlantLocation, 
 "PlantLocation", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlWarehouses", 
@class = "ddlWarehouses" })
                <br /><br />
                <label id="AddNewRow_Lbl" class="AddNewRow_Lbl">Add New Row: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input_Location, new { id = 
"Input_Location", Class = "NewRow", placeholder = "Location" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input_Section, new { id = 
 "Input_Section", Class = "NewRow", placeholder = "Section" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input_TrailerNumber, new { id = 
"Input_TrailerNumber", Class = "NewRow", placeholder = "TrailerNumber" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input_CarrierName, new { id = 
"Input_CarrierName", Class = "NewRow", placeholder = "CarrierName" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input_CommodityLoadStatus, new { id = 
"Input_CommodityLoadStatus", Class = "NewRow", placeholder = "CommodityLoadStatus" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input_PlantLocation, new { id = 
"Input_PlantLocation", Class = "NewRow", placeholder = "PlantLocation" })
                <button id="NewRowSubmitButton" type="submit" 
OnClick="NewRowSubmitButton_Click()">Submit</button>
               
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div id="content">
                @webGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                 htmlAttributes: new { @id = "webGrid" },
                 columns: webGrid.Columns(
                     webGrid.Column(header: "Actions", format:@<span class="link">
                            <!--Add Checkbox here-->
                         
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SelectedMoveIsChecked, new 
  { @Class = "SelectedMoveIsChecked", @id = "SelectedMoveIsChecked", @checked = false })
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SelectedMoveToChecked, new 
  { @Class = "SelectedMoveToChecked", @id = "SelectedMoveToChecked", @checked = false })
                            <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
                            <a class="Clear" href="javascript:;">Clear</a>
                            <a class="Update" href="javascript:;" 
   style="display:none">Update</a>
                            <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" 
 style="display:none">Cancel</a>
                        </span>),

    webGrid.Column(header: "LocationID", format: @<span 
 class="label">@item.LocationID</span>, style: "LocationID"),

    webGrid.Column(header: "Location", format: @<span>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationAppended, Model.LocationAppended, 
  "Section/Location", new { IReadOnlyDictionary = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = 
  "RowLocationDropDownList", @class = "RowLocationDropDownList", @visibility = "hidden", 
 @placeholder = "Location" })<br />
<span class="label">@item.Location</span>
</span>, style: "Location"),

     webGrid.Column(header: "Section", format: @<span 
 class="label">@item.Section</span>, style: "Section"),

     webGrid.Column(header: "TrailerNumber", format: @<span>
                <span class="label">@item.TrailerNumber</span>
                <input id="TrailerNumber" class="text" type="text" 
 value="@item.TrailerNumber" style="display:none" />
            </span>, style: "TrailerNumber"),

     webGrid.Column(header: "CarrierName", format: @<span>
                <span class="label">@item.CarrierName</span>
                <input id="CarrierName" class="text" type="text" 
 value="@item.CarrierName" style="display:none" />
            </span>, style: "CarrierName"),

     webGrid.Column(header: "LoadCommodityStatus", format: @<span>
                <span class="label">@item.LoadCommodityStatus</span>
                <input id="LoadCommodityStatus" class="text" type="text" 
 value="@item.LoadCommodityStatus" style="display:none" />
            </span>, style: "LoadCommodityStatus"),

     webGrid.Column(header: "DateLoaded", format: @<span 
  class="label">@item.DateLoaded</span>, style: "DateLoaded"),

     webGrid.Column(header: "PlantLocation", format: @<span>            
 <span class="label">@item.PlantLocation</span>
</span>, style: "PlantLocation"))),
                <div id="RowCountBpttom"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of 
 @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="WebGridTable">
            </div>
</div>

</form>
</div>
<script>
    //================== Checkbox Selection/Control =====================
    //$('#panel').accordion.hide();
    $("#panel").fadeToggle('777');
    $('#OpenPanelButton').click(function () {
        $("#panel").fadeToggle('777');
    });

    //Paint the rows Green that are TrailerNumber (Empty) and hide the checkboxes.
    $("#content tbody tr").each(function (i, row) {
        var $CheckBoxRowNull = $(row);
        if ($('#ddlWarehouses').val() == '') {

            $('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').attr('disabled', true);
        }

        if ($CheckBoxRowNull.find('#TrailerNumber').val() == '') {

            $CheckBoxRowNull.css('background-color', 
  '#AFE1AF').find('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').hide();
        };

        //Places Row List Boxes for ListLocation, ListSection, and SelectMoveCheckBox.
        var $CheckBoxRowChecked = $(row);
        if ($CheckBoxRowChecked.find('#TrailerNumber').val() != '') {

            $CheckBoxRowChecked.find('.RowLocationDropDownList').fadeIn('777').show(),
                
    $CheckBoxRowChecked.find('.RowSectionDropDownList').fadeIn('777').show();
            $CheckBoxRowChecked.find('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').fadeIn('777').show();
        };

        //========================= Inner Query =============================
        //When the checkbox is checked enable the dropdownlistbox and loop through to 
   disable dropdownlist box when not checked.
        $(".SelectedMoveIsChecked").change(function () {
            $('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').each(function () {

                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

                    
   $(this).closest('tr').find('select.RowLocationDropDownList').removeAttr('disabled');

                } else {

                    
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select.RowLocationDropDownList').attr('disabled', true);

                }

            });
        });

        //Check the box and the row turns red that is checked.
        $('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').click(function (i, row) {

            var $actualRow = $(row);
            var backgroundColorRedRow = $(this).is(":checked") ? "#EE4B2B;" : "5"; //Red 
  Color.
            var RowLocationDropDownList = $(this).is(":checked") ? "disabled" : false;
            $(this).closest('tr').attr('style', 'background-color: ' + 
    backgroundColorRedRow + ';')

            //Allow only one selection of the row to be checked.
            $(".SelectedMoveIsChecked").not(this).prop('checked', false);
            $(".SelectedMoveToChecked").not(this).prop('checked', false); //Green can be 
   checked when checkbox shown there (always hidden).

            if ($actualRow.find('#TrailerNumber').val() != '') {
                $actualRow.find('.RowLocationDropDownList').show(),
                    $actualRow.find('.RowSectionDropDownList').show();
            }

            //Show the Row DropDownList Box in the row that doesn't have a trailer 
   number.
            $('#content tbody tr').find('#TrailerNumber' != '')(function (i, row) {
                var $actualRow = $(row);
   $actualRow.find('.RowLocationDropDownList').fadeIn(777).fadeToggle().show(),
   $actualRow.find('.RowSectionDropDownList').fadeIn(777).fadeToggle().show();
            }).change();

            //================ Change Background Color upon Selection ==============
            //Turns all rows Green that have empty TrailerNumber values and hides all 
  the checkboxes in the green rows.
            $("#content tbody tr").each(function (i, row) {
                var $actualRowGreen = $(row);
                if ($actualRowGreen.find('#TrailerNumber').val() == '') {

                    $actualRowGreen.css('background-color', 
   '#AFE1AF').find('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').hide(); //Green Color.
                };
            });
        });

        //Change the background colors using checkbox based on conditions.
        $('#content tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
                $(this).closest('tr')
                    .attr('enabled', this.not.checked);
                //Added for when the checkbox is checked.
                var tdIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
                $('#WebGrid').find("tr (" + tdIndex + ")")
                    .attr('enabled', this.checked);
            });
        });
    });

    //Allows web grid to freeze headers.
    function dataBound(args) {
        this.element.find(".e-headercontent").removeClass("e-headercontent");
    }
    //Control the All Button to be seen when not empty.
    if ($('#ddlWarehouses').val() != '') {
        $('#ddlSectionAllButton').show();
    };

   */
    //Get selected output to alert.
    //Enable the checkbox when dropdownlist is not empty, then allow selection of 
     checkbox too be checked.

    $('select.RowLocationDropDownList').attr('disabled', true);
    $(".SelectedMoveIsChecked").change(function (i, row) {
        var $actualRow = $(row);
        $actualRowColorRed = $(row);
        //Only allow one DropDownRowList Box to be enabled when checkbox is checked.
        //When a value is selected in the dropdownlist box.
        if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() != '') {
            $("select.RowLocationDropDownList").change(function (i, row) {
                var $actualRow = $(row);
                $actualRowColorRed = $(row);

                //Checks to see if the checkbox is checked, display the alert showing 
    data and color the row red again.
                if ($('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').is(':checked') == true) {
     $('select.RowLocationDropDownList').children("option:selected").val();
                    var str = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                    var ret = str.split(" ");
                    var RowLocationID = ret[0];
                    var RowSection = ret[1];
                    var RowLocation = ret[2];
                    var ConfirmStr = "Are you sure, you want to move this row to\n 
     Section: ";
                    alert("Original: " + str + " " + ConfirmStr + " RowPageID: " + 
   RowLocationID + " Section: " + RowSection + " Location: " + RowLocation + "?");
                    var $actualRow = $(row);
                    var backgroundColorRedRow = $(this).is(":checked") ? "#EE4B2B;" : 
    ""; //Red Color.
                    $actualRow(this).closest('tr').attr('style', 'background-color: ' + 
   backgroundColorRedRow)
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //DropDownList Warehouse handler.
    $("body").on("change", "#ddlWarehouses", function () {
        $('#formYardDog')[0].submit();
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid tfoot a", function () {
        $('#formYardDog').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
        return false;
    });
    //DropDownList Section handler.
    $("body").on("change", ".ddlSection", function () {
        $('#formYardDog')[0].submit();
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid tfoot a", function () {
        $('#formYardDog').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
        return false;
    });

    //List Section Buttons handler.
    $("body").on("click", ".ddlSectionButtons", function () {
        $('#formYardDog')[0].submit();
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid tfoot a", function () {
        $('#formYardDog').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
        return false;
    });

    //Edit event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Edit", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                $(this).find(".text").show();
                $(this).find(".label").hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Clear").hide();
        row.find(".Update").show();
        row.find(".Cancel").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
    //Clear event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Clear", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                $(this).find(".text").show();
                $(this).find(".label").hide();
                span.html(input.val(null));
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Cancel").show();
        row.find(".Clear").show();
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        $(this).hide();
        var clear = {};
        clear.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
        clear.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
        clear.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
        clear.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
        clear.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
        clear.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
        clear.LoadCommodityStatus = 
  row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
        clear.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
        clear.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/ClearCustomer",
            data: '{clear:' + JSON.stringify(clear) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }); setInterval('location.reload()', 500);
    });
    //Update event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Update", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                span.html(input.val());
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });

        row.find(".Edit").show();
        row.find(".Cancel").hide();
        row.find(".Clear").show();
        $(this).hide();

        var customer = {};
        customer.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
        customer.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
        customer.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
        customer.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
        customer.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
        customer.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
        customer.LoadCommodityStatus = 
   row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
        customer.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
        customer.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
            data: '{customer:' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }); setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
    });

    //Cancel event handler.
    $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Cancel", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                input.val(span.html());
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        row.find(".Clear").show();
        row.find(".Update").hide();
        $(this).hide();
        setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
    });
</script>
 </body>
  [/Code]
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        YardDogModel model = PopulateModel(null, null);
        return View(model);
    }

    // Controls DropDownList PlantLocation/Section Selection.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string plantLocation, string section)
    {
        YardDogModel model = PopulateModel(plantLocation, section);
        return View(model);
    }

    // Population Controller. 
    public static YardDogModel PopulateModel(string country, string city)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3 entities = new 
 PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3())
        {
            YardDogModel model = new YardDogModel()
            {
                LocationDatas = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where c.PlantLocation == country && c.Section == city 
 && c.Section == c.Section && c.Location == c.Location && c.PlantLocation == country || 
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) && c.PlantLocation == 
 country
                                 select c).ToList(),

                LocationList = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Location) && c.Location != 
 null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && country == c.PlantLocation //  && country 
 == 
 c.PlantLocation// && townList == c.Location // && city == c.Section && country == 
 c.PlantLocation
                                select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Location, Value = 
 c.Location }).Distinct().ToList(),

                SectionList = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                               where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != 
 null && country == c.PlantLocation
                               select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = 
 c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),


                Section = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                           where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null 
 && country == c.PlantLocation
                           select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = 
 c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),


                PlantLocation = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where (c.PlantLocation == c.PlantLocation)
                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = c.PlantLocation, 
  Value = c.PlantLocation }).Distinct().ToList(),

                LocationAppended = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section 
 != null && country == c.PlantLocation && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TrailerNumber)
                                    select new SelectListItem { Text = c.LocationID + " 
 " + c.Section + " " + c.Location, Value = c.LocationID + " " + c.Section + " " + 
 c.Location 
 }).Distinct().ToList(),
                //LocationAppendedLbl = LocationAppended,
            };
            return model;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(LocationData customer)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3 entities = new 
  PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3())
        {
            LocationData updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                            where c.LocationID == customer.LocationID
                                            select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (customer.TrailerNumber != null) updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = 
  customer.TrailerNumber.ToUpper();
            else updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = customer.TrailerNumber = null;

            if (customer.CarrierName != null) updatedCustomer.CarrierName = 
  customer.CarrierName.ToUpper();
            else updatedCustomer.CarrierName = customer.CarrierName = null;

            if (customer.LoadCommodityStatus != null) 
  updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = customer.LoadCommodityStatus.ToUpper();
            else updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = customer.LoadCommodityStatus = 
  null;

            //Create today's Date for a timestamp of inputs. 
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            customer.DateLoaded = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt");
            updatedCustomer.DateLoaded = customer.DateLoaded;
            entities.SaveChanges();
            //Refresh(out, customer.ToString());
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    // Refresh the Form on Data changes. 
    // Clear the three columns in the Web Grid. 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClearCustomer(LocationData clear)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3 entities = new 
  PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3())
        {
            LocationData updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                            where c.LocationID == clear.LocationID
                                            select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (clear.TrailerNumber != null) updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = null;
            else updatedCustomer.TrailerNumber = clear.TrailerNumber = null;

            if (clear.CarrierName != null) updatedCustomer.CarrierName = null;
            else updatedCustomer.CarrierName = clear.CarrierName = null;

            if (clear.LoadCommodityStatus != null) updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = 
  null;
            else updatedCustomer.LoadCommodityStatus = clear.LoadCommodityStatus = null;

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class YardDogModel
{
    public List<LocationData> LocationDatas { get; set; }
    //public List<LocationData> Location { get; set; }
    public List<LocationData> TrailerNumber { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PlantLocation { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Location { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SectionList { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> LocationAppended { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Section { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ListDuplicates { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> UserName { get; set; }
    public bool SelectedMoveIsChecked { get; set; } = false;
    public bool SelectedMoveToChecked { get; set; } = false;
    public string LocationAppendedLbl { get; internal set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, including clearing the initial row after the data is moved:

```
$('select.RowLocationDropDownList').hide();

$(".SelectedMoveIsChecked").change(function (i, row) {

$actualRowColorRed = $(row);

//When a value is selected in the dropdownlist box.
if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() != '') {

    $("select.RowLocationDropDownList").change(function (i, row) {

        $actualRowColorRed = $(row);

        //Checks to see if the checkbox is checked, display the alert showing data and color the row red again.
        /////// if ($('.SelectedMoveIsChecked').is(':checked') == true) {

        $('select.RowLocationDropDownList').children("option:selected").val();
        var str = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        var ret = str.split(" ");
        var RowLocationID = ret[2];
        var RowLocationIDNum = parseInt(RowLocationID); //convert string to int.
        var RowSection = ret[0];
        var RowLocation = ret[1];

        var CurrentRowID = $(this).closest("tr").find('#LocationIDLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowLocation = $(this).closest("tr").find('#LocationLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowSection = $(this).closest("tr").find('#SectionLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowTrailerNumber = $(this).closest("tr").find('#TrailerNumberLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowCarrierName = $(this).closest("tr").find('#CarrierNameLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowLoadCommodityStatus = $(this).closest("tr").find('#LoadCommodityStatusLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowDateLoaded = $(this).closest("tr").find('#DateLoadedLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowUserName = $(this).closest("tr").find('#UserNameLbl').text();
        var CurrentRowPlantLocation = $(this).closest("tr").find('#PlantLocationLbl').text();

        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            var ConfirmStr = "Are you sure, you want to move this row From: " + CurrentRowID + " Section: " + CurrentRowSection + " Location:" + CurrentRowLocation + " TrailerNumber:" + CurrentRowTrailerNumber + " \n\n\n To \n Section: ";
            if (confirm("Confirm! " + ConfirmStr + "Original: " + str + "  RowPageID: " + RowLocationIDNum + " Section: " + RowSection + " Location: " + RowLocation + "?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";

                $("body").on("change", "select.RowLocationDropDownList", function () {
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $("webGrid td", row).each(function () {
                        if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                            span.html(input.val());
                        }
                    });

                    //Tell the row change to be where ID exists by ID Number (RowLocationIDNum).
                    var ToRow = {};
                    ToRow.LocationID = RowLocationIDNum;
                    ToRow.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
                    ToRow.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/YardDogAdmin/UpdateRowExchange",
                        data: '{ToRow:' + JSON.stringify(ToRow) + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                    });

                    // setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
                    //Set the Clear Event to clear the initial rows. 
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $("td", row).each(function () {
                        if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                            var span = $(this).find(".label");
                            var input = $(this).find(".text");
                            $(this).find(".text").show();
                            $(this).find(".label").hide();
                            span.html(input.val(null));
                            span.show();
                            input.hide();
                        }
                    });
                    row.find(".Cancel").show();
                    row.find(".Clear").show();
                    row.find(".Edit").show();
                    $(this).hide();
                    var clear = {};
                    clear.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
                    clear.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
                    clear.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
                    clear.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
                    clear.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
                    clear.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
                    clear.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
                    clear.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
                    clear.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/YardDogAdmin/ClearCustomer",
                        data: '{clear:' + JSON.stringify(clear) + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }); setInterval('location.reload()', 500);

                });
            }
            else {

                confirm_value.value = "Cancel";
                setInterval('location.reload()', 500);
            }

            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
        Confirm();

    });

}
});
```